# Performance of 'NULLS FIRST' in postgres select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres db. I want to display records with nulls before the rest of results.
Is it good practice to use NULLS FIRST on large amount of data?

```
... ORDER BY last_updated NULLS FIRST
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: The good practice is not to worry about performance prematurely.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index to support that `order by`:

```
create index on the_table (last_updated ASC NULLS FIRST)
```

Comment: after how many thousand of records should I consider using indexes?

Comment: @fat_pikachu: when your query is slower than acceptable